# Vertical align / vertical centering for custom defined \newcolumntype column

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

With the following code, I produce a table containing cells with one and two lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|P{2cm}||P{0.8cm}|P{0.8cm}|P{0.8cm}|P{0.8cm}|P{0.8cm}|P{0.8cm}|P{0.8cm}|P{0.8cm}|P{0.8cm}||}
        \hline
        \textbf{position} & \multicolumn{2}{P{2cm}|}{text no. one} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{text}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{text no. two} \\ \hline
        \textbf{other} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{towards no. one} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{away from no. one} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-} \\ \hline
        \textbf{two line text} & low          & high          & low          & high           & low          & high          & low          & high           \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: output]

I would like to define the columntype `P` in a way that it automatically also *vertically* centers text automatically if the cell spans two lines but contains only one line of text (here, the cells containing **`position`**, `text`, `text no. two` and all `low` and `high` entries).

I'm sure there is a straightforward solution but I couldn't find it either here or in the documentation of the `array` package.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Try replacing `p` with `m` as in `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`

Comment: You might also want to keep in mind that your table is currently wider than the textwidth. Instead of manually calculating the necesarry column widths, I'd recomment the use of `tabularx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

- your table is to wide for standard page layout, consequently I suggest to take two measures:

  - increase `\textwidth` (by use of the `geometry` package)
  - reduce font size to `\small`
- for table environment use `tabularx`
- define new column type `C` derived from `X` column type
- define new command for shorter writing of multi column cells

Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=25mm]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcx{O{2}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}
                 {>{\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+#1\arrayrulewidth/2\relax}C|}
                 {#2}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries\centering}m{17mm}|| *{8}{C|}}
        \hline
position    
    &   \mcx{text no. one}   
                    &   \mcx[4]{text}                   &   \mcx{text no. two}  \\ \hline
{other}    
    &   \mcx{--}         
                    &   \mcx{towards no. one} 
                            & \mcx{away from no. one}   & \mcx{--}              \\ \hline
two line text
    & low   & high  & low   & high  & low   & high      & low   & high          \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this meets the requirements

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption} % optional 
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{tabulary}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %Used to color the last column
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|XXXXXXXXX|}
\hline 
\small\centering{position} &     
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\small\centering\relax}X|}{text no. one} &     
\multicolumn{4}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+6\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth\small\centering\relax}X|}{text}                         &     
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\small\centering\relax}X|}{text no. two} \\ \hline
        \small\centering{other} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth\small\centering\relax}X|}{-} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth\small\centering\relax}X|}{towards no. one} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth\small\centering\relax}X|}{away from no. one} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth\small\centering\relax}X|}{-} \\ \hline
        \footnotesize\centering{two line text} & \footnotesize\centering{two line text}          & \footnotesize\centering{two line text}          & \footnotesize\centering{two line text}          & \footnotesize\centering{two line text}          & \footnotesize\centering{two line text}          & \footnotesize\centering{two line text}          & \footnotesize\centering{two line text}          & \footnotesize\centering{two line text}\\%    
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your code! Unfortunately, the text is not vertically centered so I am still looking for a way to do that.

Comment: sorry--I have updated code for centering--could not get the bottom line of the table keeps throwing an error

Comment: It is sufficient to load each package only once.

Comment: @Zarko  why does `hline` throw an error in the last line of the table

Comment: @jsbibra, cause of your problem is using  `\centering` in cells. Its use in cells' contents formatting is wrong. You should define column specification accordingly.